# Starting docker.service fails with "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name"

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, centos7

I've just finished installing docker in a server with Centos, but failed to execute `sudo service docker start`. Executing `sudo service docker restart` and reboot the server doesn't help.

- The report error by executing `sudo dockerd`:

```
Error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to program FILTER chain: iptables failed: iptables --wait -I FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1)
```

- It seems like `docker0` cannot be found, so I have checked the iptables by `ip a`:

```
...
6: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:81:95:ec:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- The docker0 exists but its state is `DOWN`, I don't know if it's the reason.
- Some information about my docker (`docker --version`) and system environment (`uname -a`):

> Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf583a

> Linux xxxxxxxxxxxxx 4.19.91-009.ali4000.alios7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 25 10:47:38 CST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Currently I don't know how to fix it.

---

### Update

- The result of executing `sudo iptables -S` is as follows:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
```

Comment: The error is about  `iptables` (which has nothing to do with the `ip` command), not about the `docker0` interface. Docker is not creating the `docker0` interface because it cannot create the necessary iptables firewall rules. Is this a stock CentOS system? Have you upgraded packages since the last time you rebooted? Can you run the command `iptables -S` as `root` without errors?

Comment: @larsks  Thanks,
- I have update packages by `sudo yum upgrade`
- The return of executing `sudo iptables -S` is updated as above.